# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 - nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to retrieve a specific system note below:

```
var noteSearch = search.create({
        type: record.Type.NOTE,
        columns: ['id', 'title', 'notetype', 'notedate', 'note'],
        filters: [ 
             search.createFilter({
                    name: 'id',
                    operator: search.Operator.EQUALTO,
                    values: 33
                })
            ]
});
var noteSearchResultSet = noteSearch.run();
```

The error I'm getting:

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_INVALID_SRCH_COL","message":"An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column, or is not in proper syntax: id.","stack":["Error\n at Object.onRequest (...)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"SSS_INVALID_SRCH_COL","details":"An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column, or is not in proper syntax: id.","userEvent":null,"stackTrace"
```

**EDIT:**

internalid has same error:

```
var noteSearch = search.create({
            type: record.Type.NOTE,
            columns: ['internalid', 'title', 'notetype', 'notedate', 'note'],
            filters: [ 
                search.createFilter({
                    name: 'internalid',
                    operator: search.Operator.EQUALTO,
                    values: 33
                })
            ]
        });
```

The note in question:

[image]

Comment: `id` should be `internalid`.

Comment: @W.S. if I wanted to filter for the transaction instead what would I use? Same error pops up putting 'transaction' even though it's a field on the XML image

Comment: @W.S. same issue with internalid. Same error

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-search-export/gglbgdfbkaelbjpjkiepdmfaihdokglp

Comment: Create the search in the UI and export through this extension.

Comment: The field name from the xml aren’t identical. Don’t know why.

Comment: The error probably refers to another field after update to internalid, no longer id?

Comment: @W.S. resolved the issue. Operator issue. Was supposed to change to:  search.Operator.IS. If you want to put that as an answer I will accept, else I will close the question

Answer (score 0):

Try using another filter type: 'is' maybe. I guess the code below could work using either 'id' or 'internalid'.

```
var noteSearch = search.create({
            type: record.Type.NOTE,
            columns: ['internalid', 'title', 'notetype', 'notedate', 'note'],
            filters: [ 
                ['internalid', 'is', 33]
            ]
        });
```